# Why is Oracle giving me a missing right parentheses error when I am not missing a right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to create a script in Oracle and keep getting an error saying I am missing the right parentheses - when I am not. please help.

```
create table driver 
( 
    d_id INT(1), 
    d_name VARCHAR(45), 
    d_contact CHAR(10), 
constraint driver_d_id_PK Primary Key(d_id) 
);    
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

create table limo 
( 
    l_id INT(1), 
    l_callsign VARCHAR(45), 
    l_type VARCHAR(45), 
constraint limo_l_id_PK Primary key(l_id) 
);    
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

create table clients 
( 
    c_id INT(1), 
    c_name VARCHAR(45), 
    c_contact CHAR(10), 
    c_methpmt VARCHAR(25), 
constraint clients_c_id_PK Primary key(c_id) 
);    
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

create table qualify 
( 
    q_id INT(1), 
    q_l_id INT(1), 
    q_d_id INT(1), 
constraint qualify_q_id_PK Primary key(q_id), 
constraint qualify_q_l_id_FK Foreign key(q_l_id) references LIMO(l_id), 
constraint qualify_q_d_id_FK Foreign key(q_d_id) references DRIVER(d_id)  
);    
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

create table rental 
( 
    r_id INT(1), 
    r_date DATE, 
    r_fee INT(4), 
    r_c_id INT(1), 
    r_q_id INT(1), 
constraint rental_r_id_PK Primary key(r_id), 
constraint rental_r_c_id_FK Foreign key(r_c_id) references CLIENTS(c_id), 
constraint rental_r_q_id_FK Foreign key(r_q_id) references QUALIFY(q_id)    
);    
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: Please format your code. If you don't know how, use Google with a search like "how to format code on StackOverflow" - then follow the links.

Comment: Int have no length, it is a synonym for `number(19)`

Answer (score 2):

The error is misleading. You have a parenthesis where it doesn't belong and Oracle gets confused. There must be no parentheses after `INT`.

If you want a numeric with a specific length, use `NUMBER` instead.

(And in Oracle we use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`, and we don't use `CHAR` either.)

```
CREATE TABLE driver 
(
  d_id NUMBER(1),
  d_name VARCHAR2(45),
  d_contact VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT driver_d_id_PK PRIMARY KEY (d_id)
);
```

`NUMBER(1)` allows single digits only, i.e. numbers from -9 to +9.